# Selenium return error without detailed info about error. How to identify error?

Tags: selenium

When I run my Selenium/Python script it shows the following error, which has no typical error info attached (ie. NoSuchElementException,...). All I got is the following output:

```
**Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x0045ACD3+2075859]
Ordinal0 [0x003EEE61+1633889]
Ordinal0 [0x002EB7BD+571325]
Ordinal0 [0x0031AC2F+764975]
Ordinal0 [0x0031AE1B+765467]
Ordinal0 [0x0034D0F2+970994]
Ordinal0 [0x00337364+881508]
Ordinal0 [0x0034B56A+963946]
Ordinal0 [0x00337136+880950]
Ordinal0 [0x0030FEFD+720637]
Ordinal0 [0x00310F3F+724799]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0070EED2+2769538]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00700D95+2711877]
GetHandleVerifier [0x004EA03A+521194]
GetHandleVerifier [0x004E8DA0+516432]
Ordinal0 [0x003F682C+1665068]
Ordinal0 [0x003FB128+1683752]
Ordinal0 [0x003FB215+1683989]
Ordinal0 [0x00406484+1729668]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76316939+25]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77C98FD2+1218]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77C98F9D+1165]**
```

I use

```
try:
   #code goes here
except Exception as e:
   print(str(s))
```

How to detect where and why the error occures as ordirar try/except does not help much?

Comment: Check webdriver logs

Comment: remove the `print(str(s))` and replace it with `raise e` it should show you the full error traceback

Comment: There is no meaningful way for Python to know what happened inside your browser. It's not a Python error.

Answer (score -1):

One way to catch the error is to do:

```
try:
   #code goes here
except Exception as e:
   error_msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__))
   print(error_msg)
```